# A question about normal matrices and length value

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I was given the following question, and I find it hard to prove.

> Let $A \in \Bbb C^{N \times N}$ be normal matrix. Prove that the following equation is correct $$\| (A+I)v \| = \|(A^* + I)v\|$$

---

My thoughts:
If A was unitary, so the equation was correct since A will not change v's length. But this matrix is normal, not unitary.
There is no helpful information about A that lets me guess that A* = A.
So the only piece of information I have is that AA* = (A*)A, and that A is diagonalized under complex numbers. Means it has eigenvalues and eigenvectors.
The only thing I can think about is that MAYBE if x is an eigenvalue for A with eigenvector t, so x is also an eigenvalue for A* with eigenvector t.
But I'm not quite sure about this sentence, so I don't think about using it to solve this question.
Can anyone please hint me to the solution for this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tell whoever gave you the question that the choice of notation is not great.  I edited a bit, please edit the rest.

Comment: Hint: express *squared* norms in terms of inner products.

Answer (score 1):

A normal matrix can be diagonalized in an **orthonormal** basis. It means that there exists $P$ such that $A=P^* D P$, where $D$ is diagonal and $P$ is unitary.

So your question is equivalent to prove that $\Vert \Delta w\Vert=\Vert \Delta^* w\Vert$ , where $\Delta$ is a diagonal matrix and $w$ is a complex vector (missing lines of computations  are left to you).

If $z_1,\ldots, z_n$ are the diagonal entries of $\Delta$, squaring everything shows that it remains to prove the equality $\sum_i \vert z_i w_i\vert^2=\sum_i \vert z_i^* w_i\vert^2$, which is true since a complex number and its conjugate have same modulus.